# Can you please help me improve my toolkit?

Tags: tools, hand-tools

This is very basic I know . . . but I really could use some help organizing my tool kit.  I'm in my twenties and trying to get more handy around the house, but having a mess of a toolbox drives me crazy!

A lot of my tools came from my great grandfather, who apparently was a bricklayer.  I suspect that there's a thing or two he might've needed that I won't. I really only want to have the essentials. Also, i'd like to upgrade tools wherever appropriate (the tape measure is not great, for example; also, some of the flat head screwdrivers have become worn and rounded after decades of use.

I mostly just mount things on my wall such as picture frames and guitars.  I also have worked with shelving brackets as well as door hinges (to attach paint canvases together).  I want to save up for a nice cordless power drill.  I've needed hex keys and socket wrenches before.  Also, the plastic box of small screw drivers is super annoying because it always spills open once it's in the toolkit.

I'm sorry for such a basic and vague question, and I don't know if it will be useful to others on this site, but I would really appreciate your suggestions for how can I have a minimalist but quality and convenient toolkit I can be proud of!

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLmiw.jpg) are the current contents of my toolkit.

Thank you!!

Comment: Just go to your home store and check out their basic tool kits.Then add tools as you need then. Be proud of your work, not the tools.

Comment: I posted an answer, but this will likely get closed as "opinion based".

Comment: The challenge here is that “handyness”, as an ideal form, is a jack of all trades, so if your goal is to be more handy, that’s like saying you want to be able to handle any home maintenance issues that might occur. But chances are, there are quite a few areas that you’re still likely to hire a professional to fix.  Can you narrow it down and tell us what areas you wouldn’t be comfortable working on? For example roof, electrical, plumbing, framing carpentry, finish carpentry, insulating, drywall hanging/mudding, painting, tiling, masonry, etc?

Comment: If the answer is “none of the above” and you just want to hang pictures on the wall, you’ll need a stud finder, a 12V cordless screwdriver, a hammer, a tape measure, and a bullet level. Or just the level and some 3M Command strips. ‍♂️

Comment: Nothing wrong with getting a grinder and being able to touch up those flat-tip screwdrivers, then sharpening drills etc.

Comment: Rather than tossing "old, rounded" screwdrivers, learn to fettle them, and put them into fine fettle. You can do that with sandpaper and a flat surface, or a whetstone, or a powered grinder, in increasing order of expense and room taken up.

Comment: If you find yourself shopping for a cordless drill/driver, don't fall for the "20V is better than 18V" marketing nonsense. They're the same thing since both are 5-cell batteries but, imo, the 18V tools' marketing is more honest.

Comment: This is off topic as the classic [opinion-based and open-ended question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Voting to close.

Answer (score 5):

I think for most casual DIY (certainly for myself, but I don't know how typical I am) you buy tools as you need them. When you do, the choices are "cheap and if it doesn't last I don't care because I won't need it again for a long time, if ever", "medium quality and *should* last a while" and "top of the line". Based on your description, I would go for that middle range. I highly recommend going to either a well-stocked traditional hardware store or a big box (Home Depot or Lowes in my area) and browse the tool aisle. It will usually be fairly obvious what falls into the 3 categories - you (mostly) get what you pay for.

Along with some other tools, you already have: Hammer, pliers, small pipe wrench, small level - those are all useful for just about any homeowner.

As for what to get, a few specifics come to mind:

- Screwdrivers - Minimum, a 6-in-1 (two sizes flat head, two sizes phillips head, two sizes nut driver) but a decent set of several screwdrivers of varying sizes, both flat head and phillips head, is a good idea. You can never have too many screwdrivers...
- Needle nose pliers
- Electrical - non-contact voltage tester and a decent multimeter are really helpful for both diagnostics and safe repairs. Unlike most other tools, for electrical it is really important to get *safe* tools, which generally means either a name brand (e.g., Klein) or purchase from a physical store (because the physical stores are required to, and generally pretty careful about it, only sell properly listed tools (e.g., UL or ETL).
- Cordless Drill/Driver

The last item is the biggie. My recommendation is to pick a brand you are comfortable with somewhere in the 18V - 20V range and stick with it. Typically you start with a basic drill/driver, battery and charger and add more tools later as you need them. There have been some [questions](https://diy.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=impact%20driver) here recently about hammer drills (for masonry) and impact drivers (for driving screws faster/easier than an ordinary drill/driver) so those are worth looking at as well. The basic idea is to pick a brand you are comfortable with (I use Home Depot's Ryobi, but there are many others, some specific to one store, some available "everywhere") and add more tools when you need them for particular projects, using the same batteries and chargers to save money.

Along with a cordless drill/driver, get a set of drill bits and screwdriver bits (hex bits of all types - flat, phillips, torx, etc.).

Beyond that, buy tools as you need them.

Comment: I use any excuse to buy a new tool.  Even if I only use it once (which is almost never), it's still cheaper than renting a tool for several days, and much cheaper than hiring a contractor to do the work.  "I can put in hardwood for 1/3 to 1/4 what a flooring contractor would charge, but I have to buy a $300 nailer".

Comment: @ I do agree but for a new / young DIYer that nailer may take an equally expensive air compressor, but good ones can last decades for DIY.

Comment: @EdBeal even cheap air compressors last a while… mine still seems to be working fine after nearly a decade and it was very cheap. Now I think I jinxed it.

Comment: You mention Phillips screwdrivers. My wife seems incapable of using Pozidriv when needed, and can't work out why the two aren't identical. In some parts of the world, only Pozi are used.

Comment: This! I had a few cheap hand and power tools as a newly married guy living in a rental. When we bought a house, we bought supplies for a project and whatever cheap tools we thought we'd need for the project. We quickly realized the cheap tools were, well, _cheap_, and bought quality upgrades for the things we used the most. I've still got and regularly use the power miter saw I bought in 1993. I bought an upgrade 2 years ago with greater capacity and I end up using _both_ on many projects.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't know what tools you'll need and/or don't know what tools you'll use the most, it makes no sense invest in such tools. As a recent first-time homeowner, I too have faced the limitations of the motley collection of tools I've inherited, scrounged, and found. I've greatly expanded my tool set in the past couple years, but have tried to do so in a way that 1. reduces cost and 2. provides the most value. Based on my experience and current market conditions, if I had to do it over again, this is what I would do.

1. Buy the largest but cheapest bundle of tools you can. Many come with organizers or a toolbox and include wrenches, drivers, chisels, pry bars, snips, etc. If bought on clearance (often post-holidays) you can get about 50 tools for $30. You'll have a complete but basic set of tools that cover about 2/3rds of typical household tasks. The tools should be of the cheapest quality possible, read on.
2. Use the cheap tools to do projects you've been putting off. While doing this, pay attention to how certain tools work and feel in your hand. If something hurts or it tedious, consider if a better tool would help or if the job just sucks.
3. After a fair bit of use, maybe 6 months, forensically examine the tools. Anything that is worn down or broken is a tool you've used and likely will use. Set it in a keeper pile. Anything that is still brand-new is probably not important to you, and you will have one if needed, so don't worry about that.
4. upgrade your keeper pile with true keepers.

Most of the best (for me) tools I own were found at Habitat for Humanity ReStore for a few bucks each or less. Buy "forever" tools made in the USA from quality parts, they were built to last. Problem with them is selection; it varies constantly. Become a regular for a bit and scoop up the good stuff at the start of the week.

For stuff you need and they don't have, "Harbor Fright" is your friend. You can get decent-quality hand and power tools for a fraction of box-store costs. These are great "first" tools and get the job done. I love their $2-5 stuff like snips, odd drivers, chisels, squares, clamps, nut+bolt sets, etc.  They also have good $20 stuff like sawzalls, compressor attachments, sanders, heat guns, oscillating saws, all those kind of secondary but nice tools. If you find yourself wearing a "2nd gen" tool out, invest in a better tool. At that point, you'll have three copies of your most-used tools, backups which are guaranteed to come in handy at some point.

Comment: Get cheap things.  Upgrade things you are wearing out.   Things not wearing out don't require upgrade.   Selection by evolution.   I like it.

Comment: I'll second the notion of getting tools at the freight harbor. Their quality has improved drastically over the last 20 years, and many (all?) of their hand tools have life time warranties that they honor with no questions asked - I've replaced several broken tools over the last 12 months - it's inconvenient, but free (except for the trip to the store). AIUI, the "super quality" tool truck tools do _not_ have a warranty - when one breaks (and they do), you buy a new one. That's why the tool truck stops by the shop every month.

Answer (score 1):

If you have few tools then you need versatile tools that can do a lot of different things. Basic survival kit:

[image]

Screwdriver + a box of bits. Must have magnetic bit holder, enough length, and a hex shaft to grab it with a wrench for stubborn screws. A handle that fits your hand well is more important than brand or price. Avoid useless gimmicks like ratchet, bit carrier in the handle that falls off on your face when you screw something on the ceiling, etc. This should cover 90% of your screwdriver needs. Flexibility is nice, you just change the bit. And when the bit is busted, you don't change the screwdriver.

[image]

Try to get a bit kit where all the bits face up. Then you take your screw and stick it on them, which makes it much easier to quickly find out which one fits.

A cheap bit that you have is better than a high quality expensive one that you haven't. The only ones that need to be in pristine condition are PH/PZ, especially PH2 for drywall. Even the cheap ones last pretty long unless you go BRAAPPPPPP with the drill.

Extra screwdrivers:

If the screw head is at the bottom of a hole, and the bit won't fit in the hole to reach the screw, then you either need a dedicated screwdriver, or a set of long bits. Long bits that are not thin just make your toolbox heavier and don't reach into holes.

[image]

A small ratchet wrench with the usual bits. One of the hex bits should be the right size to fit a screwdriver bit instead of a nut, which turns the ratchet wrench into a corner screwdriver. You also need the adapter to stick the hex nut bits on the screwdriver and the cordless drill.

[image]

For the "survival" part of the "survival kit", electrician's screwdrivers with an insulated shaft. Preferably one that lights up when it touches a live wire. Pick the bits that fit whatever is used in electrical appliances where you live, usually flat or PZ2.

[image]

Besides that, the basic kit should include a few good pliers. For these it's important to pick a quality brand.

[image]

The pipe wrench is very versatile. Needs sharp hard teeth, big handle, and locking jaws like Knipex Cobras. The needle nose I use most is the one with the short nose. It must have teeth and, if it is good quality, when it is closed the teeth should mate/mesh for best grip. If the teeth do not mate correctly, it's too cheap. You also get a free wire cutter.

Box cutter. This one should have a lock that 100% works so the blade doesn't pull out, and **no gimmicks** like "automatic blade change" and whatever. These tend to go with a lock that doesn't work, and then you cut yourself.

[Tape measure](https://www.toolstation.fr/metre-a-ruban-magnetique-bahco/p99898). Auto-lock, so the tape stays out and doesn't reel back in until you push the button. This one has a grabby bit at the end that actually grabs, with magnets on it, and it can go pretty far without bending.

Besides, you also need:

- Earmuffs that actually work (ie, 3M)
- Safety glasses (I use cycling glasses from Decathlon, quite cheap)
- Gloves
- N95 mask if you make a lot of dust

Extras: cordless drill, something to sharpen your chisel (and kitchen knives too) ; the big flathead screwdriver that's mostly used as crowbar/pry tool, sandpaper, a bunch of wago 221,

...and of course something to put all that stuff in.

This Stanley Fatmax pouch is my favorite. It fits in a backpack, so I can go see the tenants and fix stuff without having to carry a huge heavy toolbox. And you put it on a table, it opens, and you can see all your tools without any hiding at the bottom of the pile.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A tool belt can be a wonderful thing. It lets you quickly grab all the tools you'll need for most jobs, keeps them at hand while you're working, follows you up ladders, ... . Mine is loaded with the following:

- Three flat-bladed screwdrivers: 1/8", 3/16" and 1/4".
- Two Phillips screwdrivers: #1 and #2.
- A ratcheting screwdriver (SnapOn SSDMR4B) with extra bits: flat-blade 3/16" and 1/4"; Phillips #1, #2, #3; square drive #0, #1 and #2; and Pozidriv #2.
- Needlenose pliers.
- Tongue-and-groove pliers ("Channellock" or similar): 1/2" and 1 1/2" jaw openings.
- 8" adjustable wrench.
- Electrical crimper/cutter/stripper with screw cutter.
- Small pair of scissors.
- Utility knife with spare blades.
- 12-foot locking tape measure.
- Non-contact voltage tester.
- Small LED flashlight.
- Mechanical pencil and permanent marker.
- Toothbrush. (Handy for cleaning screw threads and miscellaneous crud.)
- Roll of electrical tape.

Tips:

- A ratcheting screwdriver with bits stored in the handle is a great general purpose tool, but it's nice to be able to just grab the right screwdriver and not have to fiddle with bits, hence the collection I carry. The regular drivers can also be used incorrectly, e.g. to pry up a hinge pin, or on items that don't benefit from magnets, e.g. mounting disk drives.
- Do get a Pozidriv bit (or several) and learn to recognize the difference in screw heads. If you work on Japanese equipment, e.g. motorcycles, then get a set of JIS driver bits. The right bit really does work better than using a worn Phillips bit on anything with a cross.
- Get the best tools you can justify. They are a pleasure to use. (And a pain when stolen, loaned to an abuser, dropped into a black hole, ... .) I've been amazed at how Enderes Tools screwdrivers resist wear, though not arcs.
- In general, the third time I need a special tool I'll buy it. The first two times I'll try to wing it with the current basement full of tools.
- An engineered resin ("plastic") toolbox is less destructive than a metal one when it bumps into drywall, furniture, ... . Rubbermaid used to make a variety of sturdy ones. Sigh.
- An extra nail pocket on the tool belt makes it easier to carry hardware, wire nuts, ..., when you need them at hand, e.g. working from a ladder or while holding something in place with one hand.
- My tool belt travels in tote box with other tools: claw hammer, flat pry bar, digital voltmeter with accessories, circuit tracer, safety glasses, hearing protection, nuisance dust protection, ... . There is room to toss in task specific tools and consumables.
- Consider adding a good LED headlamp.
- Check out the tackle boxes, lure organizers and the like at the local fishing supply store. They often have great boxes for organizing bits, parts, ..., that have functional latches and won't shatter.